# How to write a function to check model assumptions for a linear model in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm making a lot of models in R and trying to check the model assumptions for all of them. It would be awesome if I could write a function to do it all in one go, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I have:

```
assumptionfunction <- function(y, modelobject){
    plot(x)
    plot(y, x$residuals)
    qqnorm(x$residuals)
}
```

And I'm getting lots of errors.

Comment: Is `modelobject` the same as `x`? Because you have `modelobject` as an input, but you're not using it inside the function. Then you're using `x`, which is not an input. That being said, when you actually run `lm` do you specify `y=T, x=T`? If you don't, I don't think `lm` is storing them by default.

Comment: you can do this already, `mod = lm(mpg ~ wt, mtcars) ; par(mfrow=c(2,3)) ; plot(mod, which=1:6)`
`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating your own function, you can use an existing one. The beautiful `check_model()` function from the `performance` package does just that:

```
library(performance)
library(see)
model <- lm(mpg ~ wt * cyl + gear, data = mtcars)
check_model(model)
```

[image]

If you insist on using some objective tests, there is the `gvlma` package.

```
library(gvlma)
gvlma(model)

ASSESSMENT OF THE LINEAR MODEL ASSUMPTIONS
USING THE GLOBAL TEST ON 4 DEGREES-OF-FREEDOM:
Level of Significance =  0.05     

                      Value p-value                Decision
Global Stat        1.770046  0.7780 Assumptions acceptable.
Skewness           0.746520  0.3876 Assumptions acceptable.
Kurtosis           0.003654  0.9518 Assumptions acceptable.
Link Function      0.927065  0.3356 Assumptions acceptable.
Heteroscedasticity 0.092807  0.7606 Assumptions acceptable.
```

Now if you don't like `gvlma` because it doesn't explicitly name the tests used and gives Skewness and Kurtosis but not overall normality from, say, Shapiro-Wilk, I made a convenience function. It gets all tests names and assumptions at once with the total number of assumptions that are not respected. You can take it and modify it to suit your needs.

```
# Load the function:
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RemPsyc/niceplots/master/niceAssFunction.R")
View(niceAss(model))

Interpretation: (p) values < .05 imply assumptions are not respected. 
Diagnostic is how many assumptions are not respected for a given model or variable.
```

[image]

Applied to a list of models:

```
# Define our dependent variables
(DV <- names(mtcars[-1]))

# Make list of all formulas
(formulas <- paste(DV, "~ mpg"))

# Make list of all models
models.list <- sapply(X = formulas, FUN = lm, data = mtcars, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)

# Make diagnostic table
(ass.table <- do.call("rbind", lapply(models.list, niceAss)))

# Use the Viewer for better results
View(ass.table)
```

[image]